# Authenticating users using access tokens - WCF  Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-data-services

We are  developing a set of  WCF Services for implementing the business logic in an application. The application using role based security for this application. The users are categorized in to different roles like Administrators , Managers , Employees etc. We want to ensure that users belonging to specific roles can only call specific methods. The WCF Services exposes a http based endpoint as well as a TCP based end point

We want to implement authentication using acess tokens. any help is appreciated

Regards
Sabarish

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Answer (score 1):

WCF data service doesn't support TCP endpoint - it can be exposed only through HTTP endpoint with `webHttpBinding`. Also I'm not sure how you want to apply standard role based security to data service resources. Check authorization section in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728284.aspx).

It leads me to questions: Do you know the difference between WCF Service and WCF Data Service? What exactly are you using?

Comment: Its a WCF service with basicHttpBinding  and nettcpbinding

Comment: That should be fine... we have 2 set of clients for the service - a web application as well as a WPF application ... Was thinking that tcp binding might be faster